# Press a Key to Open a file in a Java program

Tags: java, keypress

I developed a Java program that open specific files when the user clicks on a Jlabel. The click event worked very well. I added a keypress event so that a user can press a key on the keyboard to open the file but it's not working. 
Can anyone show me how to use a key event listener to open a file or file path in Java. Am new to Java an still learning.  I need your help. Please

Comment: Show us what you have done already. If you have the keypress done and file opening done, then there is probably a little mistake that doesn't allow you to put it together successfuly. Don't make others write the whole code for you. Let us help you fix yours

Answer (score 1):

In order to make that to work you need to understand how is the  `KeyListener` working.. the widget needs to have the focus gained in order to catch that event and IMHO set the focus on a JLabel makes no much sense... hence in this case you can just work with a keyListener assigned to the `JFrame`

so my suggestion would be to work on a keylistener on the JFrame and define the keys you need for the open the file there..

## Example:

```
public class Test extends JFrame implements KeyListener{
    .....
    .....
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Comment: Private void week1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) . . . . . . . . . . . . . {try.

Comment: Private void week1MouseClicked (java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt {
{
 try
{
  Runtime. getRuntime(). exec('' '') 
}  catch. (Exception e) 
{  JOptionPane. showMessageDailog(null,''Error'') ;

  } 
} 
  } 


Private void week1KeyPressed (java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt {
if (e.getKeyCode() ==
    KeyEvent. VK_A{
{

try
{
  Runtime. getRuntime(). exec('' '') 
}  catch. (Exception e) 
{  JOptionPane. showMessageDailog(null,''Error'') ;

  } 
} 
  }